# How to limit the columns of an array in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a 4: 3 matrix and I would like to take only 2: 3.

Is it possible to delimit using the DelimitedFiles command?
How should I use it?

```
Q = convert(Matrix, ACT[2:3])#I would like to omit the 2:3
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following `Matrix`:

```
julia> a = collect(reshape(1:12,(4,3)))
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5   9
 2  6  10
 3  7  11
 4  8  12
```

You can select a subarray in two ways - either making a copy of the desired part or creating a view.

Making a copy (a new object is created and `Array`'s data is copied:

```
julia> a[1:2,:]
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5   9
 2  6  10
```

Creating a `view`. This is in many scenarios much faster because the data is not copied:

```
julia> view(a, 1:2, :)
2×3 view(::Array{Int64,2}, 1:2, :) with eltype Int64:
 1  5   9
 2  6  10
```

For creating the view you can also use a macro - in this case your code will be more similar to the one that copies the data:

```
julia> @view a[1:2,:]
2×3 view(::Array{Int64,2}, 1:2, :) with eltype Int64:
 1  5   9
 2  6  10
```

Each of those views can be shown using the command `display` and this is the standard way to handle showing them.
However if you want to use `DelmitedFiles` you can, for example:

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles;writedlm(stdout, @view a[1:2,:])
1       5       9
2       6       10
```